# wp-admin shows blank page, how to fix it?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working with WordPress 3.5.8. Yesterday I made some changes into it to a friend. I don't know what happened, but after some time when I try to log in at wp-admin side and execute URL `www.mysite.com/wp-admin` it shows me a blank page. How do I solve this? I have searched over the internet and blogs. I found it could be related to hosting problems or brute force-attack, but I don't think that that's what happened to my site.

Links I visited:

- http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-admin-wont-load-shows-blank-page
- http://wordpress.org/support/topic/brute-force-attacks-and-wordpress?replies=1
- http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-admin-wont-load-shows-blank-page
- http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-admin-blank-page
- http://wordpress.org/support/topic/blank-page-on-wp-admin

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try turning on [WP Debug](http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG). If this is happening due to a PHP error (which I bet that it is), you will be able to see what's going on and fix the error.

Comment: When mysql_connect(); The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/tempotravellerrentalchennai.in/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1520..  Any upate for sql to sqli..?

Comment: I enabled it. And now?

Answer (score 54):

After dozens of times trying to fix this problem reading forums and posts, reinstalling WordPress, removing white spaces, putting lines of code in wp-config.php, index.php, admin.php, I fixed the issue just by renaming the `plugins` folder to `"pluginss"` in FTP. So wordpress asked me to update the database. I updated and I could enter at `/wp-admin`. A plugin was causing some conflict, so when I rename the `plugins` folder, all plugins automatically has been disabled.

As I was inside the `/wp-admin` dashboard, I could rename the `"pluginss"` folder to the regular name and start to activate all the plugins one by one and see what plugin was broken.

Now is 100% fine.

Comment: I've been trying to solve this problem for hours, and this simply worked, after trying like 10 different things.

Comment: Good way to figure out the issue

Comment: Yes, this normally helps but if you have a wrong function like extra { or missing } you need to enable the debug option to fix those lines.

Comment: such a brilliant idea! plugin or theme conflict! thank you very much!

Answer (score 15):

Go to your `functions.php` page and delete any spaces immediately above or below your **PHP** tags.

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same problem and I tried many things such as trying to login through wp-login.php instead of /wp-admin and adding ob_start() in /wp-admin/index.php (if you hit the url /wp-admin it goes for /wp-admin). It showed login page but entering the username and password shows an error like "cookies are blocked due to unexpected output".

I finally got the solution: **it happens because the theme or plugins that you installed are not supported.**

How to check and fix:

- **Rename the plugin folder name and theme folder name.** If opening /wp-admin and entering a valid username and password the dashboard is shown, then it worked.
- Revert the folder name of plugin and theme, then **activate the themes and plugins one by one**, cross-checking with /wp-admin. You will find out the unsupported plugin or theme.

Comment: It worked, but the strange thing is that enabling the debug doesn't help, no any errors: on the page, wp-debug (missing), error_log empty no any clue. Now investigating the plugins.

Answer (score 3):

> I also had a blank screen for my blog. The solution was to copy up a backup copy of wp-config,php somehow the 'live' wp-config.php had been replaced with a file size of zero.

In my case I had the same problem. Helped remove the wp-config.php file.
Wordpress created new wp-config.php file and wp-admin is working flawlessly now.
Rename plugins, themes folder does not help.

Answer (score 2):

[6] was spot on.  I had the same problem 
ie a blank screen where wp-admin should have been
Renaming plugins to pluginss let me get back in.

I also had a blank screen for my blog.
The solution was to copy up a backup copy of wp-config,php
somehow the 'live' wp-config.php had been replaced with a file size of zero.

It seems that it is very important to have an off-line backup
The easy way to copy of the files is Filezilla (freeware)

You need a wordpress plugin for database backup - ie to back up all your pages and posts.
But the pros will tell you that you need to get a

Peter

Answer (score 2):

All your problem is solved right now just follow this instruction:

1. go to your themes then de activate your current theme, just put "x" in the the first letter of your theme name.

for example this is your theme folder name: "mytheme" just put "x" in the first letter like this "xmytheme" tho di activate.

2. Then after that go back to your wp-admin panel then BOOM! wp-admin accessable.
3. When you access your wp-admin panel or you are on your dashboard, again activate your theme again, but before that. REMOVE THE "X" letter you putted in your theme name.
   example: "xmytheme" just remove "x", output like this: "mytheme"
4. then activate it in your dashboard.

hope this help!.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was able to see the backend, but in my front I was getting a blank page...

Nothing about debugging and disabling themes/plugins was useful...
After some research, I've realized that my `index.php` (located at the root directory, not the theme's one) was empty!
The only content was a message saying *Silence is golden*.

Using a backup I had, I could get back my original `index.php` and get the site working again.

Comment: for me wp-login.php was empty, thank's for sharing your answer

Answer (score 2):

It might be because of a few reasons:

1. Problems in your web host.
2. Theme related errors(You can change it by renaming theme folder).
3. Plugin related errors(You can change it by renaming plugin folder).
4. An Empty line in your wp-config file.
5. Code errors that can be seen by enabling Debug mode.

   "define('WP_DEBUG', true);
   // Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
   define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

   // Disable display of errors and warnings
   define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
   @ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );"
6. Remove blank space in functions.php or you can also remove the last "?>"

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem a few minutes ago, the problem was when I uploaded my local theme I had a bunch of  tags separating each function  I had in there I solved this by putting all the functions in one php tag... Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem (not showing /wp-admin/), when I moved my site to new host. i solve this problem by:
1. Re mane activated theme's folder
2. Install that them again and active it
3. copy and re place some customized file like .css .js from backup

Now problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this and it was a file / directory ownership issue.
Fixed via SSH and changing the ownership recursively (-R):

`chown -R ownerID:groupID /home/mydirectory/website`

Change ownerID, groupID and filepath to be relevant to your own situation.

Answer (score 1):

i have wasted a lot of time to solve it , But the only solution i find is to rename your word press plugins folder and active theme , and your wp-admin will be visible , so then you can change and check for suspected plugin or theme.

Answer (score 0):

Just reset the password, this will work.

Comment: Believe it or not, this worked for me. I was able to access wp-admin but after entering user/pass it redirects to wp-login and showed empty screen. I reset the password, enters the new password and it worked. Im now able to access wp-admin.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same problem but i renamed **contact-form-7** plugin from **/wp-content/plugins** directory to **contact-form-7-rename** and problem solved.

So this is due to unsupportable plugins or theme.

Answer (score 0):

That white screen of death happened to my blog, and what I did was that I renamed the theme and plugin, and everything was back to normal.

Comment: this is just a link for self promotion, admit it !

Answer (score 0):

In my case, wp-admin/post.php blank screen was fixed by removing the " ?> " at the end of my function.php in my child theme. I don't know how the end tag ended in there, but removing it solved my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Just visit the plugins folder and delete the last plugin you uploaded and should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I found following solution working as I was using **older version** of wordpress.

1. Open file blog/wp-admin/includes/screen.php in your favorite text
   editor.
2. on line 706 find the following PHP statement: `<?php echo self::$this->_help_sidebar; ?>`
3. Replace it with the statement: `<?php echo $this->_help_sidebar; ?>`
4. Save your changes.

Answer (score 0):

first of all check your internet its connect!

second is turn on WP_DEBUG and write this codes in wp-config.php

```
define('WP_DEBUG',true);
error_reporting('E_ALL');
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

third is rename themes and plugins folder that in wp-content folder to other name sush as

pluginss , themess

S F my english!

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue after changing the PHP version from 5.6 to 7.3 (eaphp73). So what I did was I simply changed the version to alt-php74.

So what's the problem? Probably a plugin that relied on a certain PHP extension that wasn't available on eaphp73.

Before you touch any wordpress files, just try changing your site's PHP version. You can do this in the cPanel.

And if that doesn't work, go back into the cPanel and activate every PHP extension there is. And if your site starts working at this stage, then it's probably an extension it couldn't function without. Now slowly work backwards deactivating (one at a time) ONLY the extensions you just activated.

You should be able to figure out which extension was the required feature.

Can it be a plugin that's causing the issue? Certainly. Maybe the rogue plugin just wanted that extra extension.

If changing the PHP version, and juggling with the PHP extensions didn't work, then try renaming (which automatically deactivates) one plugin folder at a time.

Answer (score -1):

I have experienced the same problem as well. The reason was, that the `functions.php` was configured wrongly.

I did the following to solve the problem:

- In my child theme, I backed up all my files
- Then I deleted all of them leaving only the `style.css` page.
- I could then log in.

On reloading my functions.php I found it was the **culprit**. I rewrote the php and it was fine.

Answer (score -1):

My case was that I had generated code for three custom content types and then just pasted all the code in functions.php without renaming the "function custom_post_type" part of each function. After renaming like e.g "function employees", it worked like a charm....it displayed.