# Wordpress page wp-admin/edit blank for almost all functions

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to figure out a solution to a problem that have occured for my father, who has absolutely no knowledge of Wordpress or what he's been doing with his page. Me myself don't have too much knowledge of Wordpress or its functions, but have tried to find a solution on my own.

The problem: After logging on to the Wordpress admin page (wp-admin/edit) from the webpage (http://[webpagename].com/wp-login.php) only the left panel is visible for almost all functions except a few. Only the following page-tabs return pages with information

- Admin->Akismet statistics
- Addons->Configure Akismet
- Tool->Backup
- Settings->Google analytics
- Settings-> MapPress
- Settings->Language
- Settings->Coming soon
- Contact

All other tabs turn out as white pages to the right. I have tried in up to date browsers Google Chrome, IE 11 and Firefox. The webpage is fully visible and functional in itself, it is only when trying to change it via wp-admin link I have problem.

I have read the answers to similiar problems in the links related to this post: [wp-admin shows blank page, how to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607611/wp-admin-shows-blank-page-how-to-fix-it) (I can not post the links myself since I am a new member).

But all of above seems to use an installed program to configure the pages and the solution mostly boils down to disable installed plugins or running the page in debug mode. Since we don't have a program installed nor have the choice to disable any plugins or configuring any files, none of these solutions are applicable as I can see it.

Does anyone know why we can't configure the web page anymore using the http://[webpagename].com/wp-login.php page?

Thank you for your time.

Regards

Rasmus

Comment: Does the settings > permalinks menu returns a blank page too?

Comment: Yes,  the tab Settings->permalink also retun blank page. Only the following page-tabs return pages with information


Admin->Akismet statistics; 
Addons->Configure Akismet; 
Tool->Backup; 
Settings->Google analytics; 
Settings-> MapPress; 
Settings->Language; 
Settings->Coming soon; 
Contact.


I have tried in up to date browsers Google Chrome, IE 11 and  Firefox.

The webpage is fully visible and functional in itself, it is only when trying to change it via wp-admin link I have problem.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however it doesn't seem to have a chance without having access to the host ftp.