# Wordpress admin page showing blank

Tags: php, wordpress

My `wp-admin` page showing blank.

I have already added `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` in `wp-config.php` file.

Still the page showing blank.

Where is the problem ? Anybody Help please ?

Comment: Can you try to rename wp-content folder and check what it is showing?

Comment: try checking the ``error_log`` file

Comment: @NewUser...If I renamed wp-content folder....my webpage is also showing blank

Comment: There might be an issue with the Headers already sent. Try to change plugin folder or theme folder and check page is showing or not. You can also check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/17607611/5772301

Comment: @OMiShah...there is no error shown in `error_log` on todays date

Comment: @ArafatRahman can you please try to download a fresh copy of wordpress and try? Also please try to add these two lines in the wp-config.php file

`define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );`

Now it should create a file called debug_log under the wp-content folder.