# My Wordpress is showing a blank page in the editor, how can I fix this?

Tags: wordpress

I manage a Wordpress site for a client, after trying to resolve some updates I cannot seem to edit anything inside the editor anymore. Everything is blank (see image). The site itself is still up and working fine. Has anyone ever encountered this?[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wp-admin shows blank page, how to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607611/wp-admin-shows-blank-page-how-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so in this case the problem was (when I checked the error log) that the update was not properly installed. Deactivated the plugins inside PHP MyAdmin and then reinstalled Wordpress manually onto site.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of reasons, why this could be happened. Like @jiali sent you a very helpful link, I would say to try and open the debugger: inside `wp-config.php` file search for `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` and change the value to `true`. Then, you propably would see what causing the error and where (either plugin or custom code, or maybe plugins conflict)